# Node js socket io app web loosing connection on production

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

Good day all, pls I have a project which you can check up on GitHub at https://github.com/timotech/screen-cast
The project works very perfect on localhost, but when deployed to heroku, it displays well, but looses web socket connection before any chat is done. Pls what can I do. 
Thanks
Tim

Comment: Can you display the basic functionality with code?

Comment: Thanks @RtmY for your reply, because of the length of the codes, I will just do a brief description. But you can get the full project on github.

Comment: Index.hml is for teachers login, to input name and select room to join. Then it navigates to emit.html for webcam emitting and chat emitting. Students join the room by going to students.hml. Then they are redirected to visualize.hml, where they can receive chats and also have access to teachers' webcam. The server is index.js. It's working very ok in localhost, teachers can chat with the students and vice versa. But connection breaks on production, when you check developer console